# Updating GUI instead of new scene

Tags: java, javafx

I currently have

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);        
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        String dd = "Hello";
        
        
        stage.setTitle("Greetings");  //creates title
        
        button_roll = new Button("Roll");
        
        StackPane layout1 = new StackPane();
        layout1.getChildren().add(button_roll);
        
        Scene scene1 = new Scene(layout1, 600, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene1);

        Label mylab = new Label();
        mylab.setText(dd);
        Scene scene2 = new Scene(mylab, 600, 600);
        
        
        button_roll.setOnAction(e -> stage.setScene(scene2));
       
        stage.show();
      
    }
```

My code currently displays "Hello" into the scene as a new scene.
I was wondering if there was a way to just update the scene1 to display the text instead of creating a whole new scene with just the text in it.

Is there terminology for what I want to do, if so what is it?
Any help would be great!

Comment: I don't see where you add the `Label` to the `Scene`.

Comment: Take the time to go through some `JavaFX` tutorials. https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/jfxpub-get_started.htm

Comment: java naming conventions please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you never add the `Label` to the `Scene`. Having the root node as `StackPane` will stack the `Label` and `Button` over each other. You need to replace `StackPane` with `VBox`, `HBox`, or a more suitable `Node`. Comments in the code.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        String helloString = "Hello";//String use in the lable once the button is pressed.
        Label lblHello = new Label();//Label that will show helloString once the button is pressed.

        Button btnRoll = new Button("Roll");//The button that will trigger the action to change the label from empty string to helloString.
        btnRoll.setOnAction((t) -> {//Set the button's action
            lblHello.setText(helloString);//set the label's text to helloString.
        });

        VBox vbLayoutRoot = new VBox(lblHello, btnRoll);//The root layout is a VBox. Add the label and the btn to the root layout.
        Scene scene = new Scene(vbLayoutRoot, 600, 600);//Add the root layout to the scene.
        stage.setScene(scene);//Set the scene.
        stage.setTitle("Greetings");  //creates title
        stage.show();//Show the stage.
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with javaFX, but maybe you should try an *EventHandler/ActionEvent*:

```
   button_roll.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
      @Override
      public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        mylab.setText("Hello");
      }
    });
```

Comment: I've tried but nothing shows in the scene after pressing the button

Answer (score -1):

You should do like this:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    String dd = "Hello";
    stage.setTitle("Greetings");  //creates title

    Button button_roll = new Button("Roll");

    StackPane layout1 = new StackPane();
    layout1.getChildren().add(button_roll);

    Scene scene1 = new Scene(layout1, 600, 600);
    stage.setScene(scene1);

    Label mylab = new Label();
    mylab.setText(dd);


    button_roll.setOnAction(e -> {
        layout1.getChildren().clear();
        layout1.getChildren().add(mylab);
    });

    stage.show();

}
```